# Xcode Build take too much time?

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, dart, cocoapods

environment:
sdk: ">=3.1.2 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
cloud_firestore: ^4.9.2
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_auth: ^4.10.0
firebase_core: ^2.16.0
firebase_storage: ^11.2.7
flutter:
sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

## #**I just add these dependecies and it take to much time **

i try flutter clean
and
flutter pub get
but after Running pod install
Xcode build take too much timee

Comment: With firebase dependencies it will take time some times more then half hour to make a build but won't effect anything else

Answer (score 0):

A working solution can be found (copied below) with more detail in [firebase/flutterfire#2751](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/2751)

**Note:** to apply, lookup the current tag for the specific repo shown, then in `ios/Podfile` add that pod entry immediately following `target 'Runner' do` like this:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '6.29.0'
```

this immediately resolved all slowness when initially implementing cloud firestore in my project (once it worked--in my case updating the tag to latest was necessary)

reference and credit [Jimmont](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37582#issuecomment-667997839)